# Why does the Python Docs state that "all immutable built-in objects are hashable"?

Tags: python, list, hash, tuples

On the [Glossary-Page](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) under the section ["*hashable*"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) of the official Python Documentation visitors can read that

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime ...
>
> ***All* of Python’s *immutable built-in objects* are hashable**, while no mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not...

This means that passing an object of the

- `int`, `float`, `long`, `complex`,
- `str`,
- `bytes`,
- `tuple` or
- `frozenset`

class to the build-in `hash()` method **must return the supposed hash-value**.

The problem is that **tuples can contain unhashable objects** (such as `list`s) and therefor **some tuples are not hashable**:

1. Create (valid) tuple consisting of hashable (`int`s and `string`) and unhashable (`list`) data types.

   ```
   >>> tuple([1, 2, [3, "4"]])  
       (1, 2, [3, '4'])
   ```
2. Hashing this tuple fails ...

   ```
   >>> hash((1, 2, [3, '4'])) 
       Traceback (most recent call last):
           hash((1, 2, [3, '4']))
       TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
   ```
3. ... although the object to hash is an immutable built-in type

   ```
   >>> type((1, 2, [3, '4']))
       <class 'tuple'>
   ```

*So, why does the Python Docs state now that "**all** immutable built-in objects are hashable", although especially the `tuple` type **can contain unhashable types**?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because one should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that one faces. This post poses no practical question.

Comment: even the TypeError points to the unhashable list (which is part of the tuple), it doesn't say unhashable type: 'tuple'

Comment: Pretty sure that this is wrong (both gramatically and semantically): `while no mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not...`

Answer (score 7):

I don't know too much about Python's hashing, but to me it looks like you're just nitpicking the text.

> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable

That's what they stated and that's true: you can hash a tuple such as `(3, 3, 2)` just fine, **tuples are hashable**.

However, if you put an unhashable list into a tuple, it can no longer be hashed *because it contains an unhashable object*. This doesn't mean that tuples are unhashable, but lists are, and thus the tuple which contains a list can no longer be hashed.

Placing non-compostable garbage into a compostable garbage bag doesn't make the bag non-compostable.

Comment: Maybe the OP could consider a patch to the Python docs to say something like "All data structures consisting entirely of Python's immutable built-in objects are hashable".